# selectize.js reset selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, selectize.js

I am using selectize.js library in my angular project and I am trying to reset my form after submit. I want to reset all select dropdowns, but when I cleared the selectize fields all options are removed.

my code:

```
$('.select-beast').each(function(){
    var _thisEl = $(this);
    $(this).selectize({
        sortField: 'text',
        onChange:function(value){

        }
    });
});
```

to reset:

```
var selectize = $select[0].selectize;
selectize.clear()
```

any suggestions?